# How can I make Cartesian product with Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, cartesian-product

I have the following collection type:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> map;
```

I would like to create unique combinations of each of `map.size()` from a single value in the collection for each Key.

For example suppose the map looks like the following:

```
A, {a1, a2, a3, ..., an}
B, {b1, b2, b3, ..., bn}
C, {c1, c2, c3, ..., cn}
```

The result I would like to get would a `List<Set<String>>` result, looking similar to (ordering is not important, it just needs to be a 'complete' result consisting of all possible combinations):

```
{a1, b1, c1},
{a1, b1, c2},
{a1, b1, c3},
{a1, b2, c1},
{a1, b2, c2},
{a1, b2, c3},
...
{a2, b1, c1},
{a2, b1, c2},
...
{a3, b1, c1},
{a3, b1, c2},
...
{an, bn, cn}
```

This is basically a counting problem, but I would like to see if a solution is possible using Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can solve this using the recursive `flatMap` chain.

First as we need to move back and forth by the map values, it's better to copy them to the `ArrayList` (this is not the deep copy, in your case it's `ArrayList` of 3 elements only, so the additional memory usage is low).

Second, to maintain a prefix of previously visited elements, let's create a helper immutable `Prefix` class:

```
private static class Prefix<T> {
    final T value;
    final Prefix<T> parent;

    Prefix(Prefix<T> parent, T value) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // put the whole prefix into given collection
    <C extends Collection<T>> C addTo(C collection) {
        if (parent != null)
            parent.addTo(collection);
        collection.add(value);
        return collection;
    }
}
```

This is very simple immutable linked list which can be used like this:

```
List<String> list = new Prefix<>(new Prefix<>(new Prefix<>(null, "a"), "b"), "c")
                          .addTo(new ArrayList<>()); // [a, b, c];
```

Next, let's create the internal method which chains flatMaps:

```
private static <T, C extends Collection<T>> Stream<C> comb(
        List<? extends Collection<T>> values, int offset, Prefix<T> prefix,
        Supplier<C> supplier) {
    if (offset == values.size() - 1)
        return values.get(offset).stream()
                     .map(e -> new Prefix<>(prefix, e).addTo(supplier.get()));
    return values.get(offset).stream()
            .flatMap(e -> comb(values, offset + 1, new Prefix<>(prefix, e), supplier));
}
```

Looks like recursion, but it's more complex: it doesn't call itself directly, but passed lambda which calls the outer method. Parameters:

- values: the `List` of original values (`new ArrayList<>(map.values)` in your case).
- offset: the current offset within this list
- prefix: the current prefix of length offset (or `null` if `offset == 0`). It contains currently selected elements from the collections `list.get(0)`, `list.get(1)` up to `list.get(offset-1)`.
- supplier: the factory method to create the resulting collection.

When we reached the end of the values list (`offset == values.size() - 1`), we map the elements of the last collection from the values to the final combination using the supplier. Otherwise we use the `flatMap` which for each intermediate element enlarges the prefix and calls the `comb` method again for the next offset.

Finally here's public method to use this feature:

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> Stream<C> ofCombinations(
        Collection<? extends Collection<T>> values, Supplier<C> supplier) {
    if (values.isEmpty())
        return Stream.empty();
    return comb(new ArrayList<>(values), 0, null, supplier);
}
```

A usage example:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // to preserve the order
map.put("A", Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"));
map.put("B", Arrays.asList("b1", "b2", "b3"));
map.put("C", Arrays.asList("c1", "c2"));

ofCombinations(map.values(), LinkedHashSet::new).forEach(System.out::println);
```

We collect individual combinations to the `LinkedHashSet` again to preserve the order. You can use any other collection instead (e.g. `ArrayList::new`).

Answer (score 15):

Cartesian product in Java 8 with forEach:

```
List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("0", "1");
List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("a", "b");

List<String> cartesianProduct = new ArrayList<>();
listA.forEach(a -> listB.forEach(b -> cartesianProduct.add(a + b)));

System.out.println(cartesianProduct);
// Output: [0a, 0b, 1a, 1b]
```

Answer (score 15):

A simpler answer, for a simpler situation where you just want to have the cartesian product of the elements of two collections.

Here's some code which uses `flatMap` to generate the cartesian product of two short lists:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> aList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> bList = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);

    Stream<List<Integer>> product = aList.stream().flatMap(a ->
            bList.stream().flatMap(b ->
                    Stream.of(Arrays.asList(a, b))));

    product.forEach(p -> { System.out.println(p); });

    // prints:
    // [1, 4]
    // [1, 5]
    // [1, 6]
    // [2, 4]
    // [2, 5]
    // [2, 6]
    // [3, 4]
    // [3, 5]
    // [3, 6]
}
```

If you want to add more collections, just nest the streams a litter further:

```java
aList.stream().flatMap(a ->
    bList.stream().flatMap(b ->
        cList.stream().flatMap(c ->
            Stream.of(Arrays.asList(a, b, c)))));
```

Comment: This is good, but the second `flatMap` and the last stream are unnecessary – you can just do `Stream<List<Integer>> product = aList.stream().flatMap(a -> bList.stream().map(b -> Arrays.asList(a, b)));`.

Comment: True, but I liked the symmetry of this code. Not optimal in efficiency as you said. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 11):

A solution that mainly operates on lists, making things a lot simpler. It does a recursive call in `flatMap`, keeping track of the elements that have already been combined, and the collections of elements that are still missing, and offers the results of this nested recursive construction as a stream of lists:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CartesianProduct {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Collection<String>> map =
                new LinkedHashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
        map.put("A", Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"));
        map.put("B", Arrays.asList("b1", "b2", "b3"));
        map.put("C", Arrays.asList("c1", "c2"));
        ofCombinations(map.values()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static <T> Stream<List<T>> ofCombinations(
            Collection<? extends Collection<T>> collections) {
        return ofCombinations(
                new ArrayList<Collection<T>>(collections),
                Collections.emptyList());
    }

    private static <T> Stream<List<T>> ofCombinations(
            List<? extends Collection<T>> collections, List<T> current) {
        return collections.isEmpty() ? Stream.of(current) :
                collections.get(0).stream().flatMap(e -> {
                    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(current);
                    list.add(e);
                    return ofCombinations(
                            collections.subList(1, collections.size()), list);
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

While it's not a Stream solution, Guava's [`com.google.common.collect.Sets`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) does that for you.

```java
Set<List<String>> result = Sets.cartesianProduct(
        Set.of("a1", "a2"), Set.of("b1", "b2"), Set.of("c1", "c2"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution, which does not use as many features from `Streams` as Tagir's example; however I believe it to be more straight-forward:

```java
public class Permutations {
    transient List<Collection<String>> perms;
    public List<Collection<String>> list(Map<String, Collection<String>> map) {
        SortedMap<String, Collection<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
        sortedMap.putAll(map);
        sortedMap.values().forEach((v) -> perms = expand(perms, v));
        return perms;
    }

    private List<Collection<String>> expand(
            List<Collection<String>> list, Collection<String> elements) {
        List<Collection<String>> newList = new LinkedList<>();
        if (list == null) {
            elements.forEach((e) -> {
                SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
                set.add(e);
                newList.add(set);
            });
        } else {
            list.forEach((set) ->
                    elements.forEach((e) -> {
                        SortedSet<String> newSet = new TreeSet<>();
                        newSet.addAll(set);
                        newSet.add(e);
                        newList.add(newSet);
                    }));
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

You can remove the `Sorted` prefix if you are not interested in ordering of elements; though, I think it's easier to debug if everything is sorted.

Usage:

```java
Permutations p = new Permutations();
List<Collection<String>> plist = p.list(map);
plist.forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s));
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Note that your solution actually uses zero Stream API features (`Collection.forEach` is not the part of Stream API). You can replace `.forEach` with good old `for-in` loop and your code will be Java 5-compatible. Also note that you store all the combinations in the memory. While this seems ok for the OP, it can become problematic with larger input. Finally there's no easy way to parallelize it.

Answer (score 2):

#### The *map-and-reduce* approach with nested loops within one stream

One outer stream can be easily converted to [`parallel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) - this can reduce the computation time in some cases. Inner iterations are implemented with loops.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVdb5swFH3Pr7iLtMqkDV3SaQ9Nmi2NJu2hkyY1b9MeXHAap8Yg27Tqqvz27PpCKAnQbSBhY59z77kfmA1/5MM0E3oTP@x2MslS42CDi2HupAoHk14vUtxaWHDjhJVc/zBpnEcOXnqA1/lgQCMM4EvGDU8g4RlweqYrUNI6ewSYLmfg1gLccyY8xs@FEonQNagRLjea9irPkJWukeTtP3KViz3lnMYsv1MyAuu4w8F7ukEFU3osZzOIjqJg33k2XZ5BBUC7QRkahXcO0VpEDyBXIHWUJlLfQ8wdB2lBpw50rlSFRhDzwq6uaD2AMopFqpSInEy1DUWSuWfvjgWTiljikBsWQbEgtM4InuDEZw35igUVviZPp3ronQHXMb2Qg3ria1e4ksoJw/wuDGeEgneFWjg5offQyt@CBTCDD60OjciMsFgsEDxaFybK8gG3WHqLOVLCpZr2mhowykrAS2PbX4c1034GKFI8wdwYTtmbzlhNbC2V9WuVGmBLEHBJUoLCVMjjmNVLUgmmsogua2WRCNVEbFuTZfMk4d6L79mMS2P9RGotTFeJjMDGFIzCG50Rahx058q3QJ7coT00jA16JzU5tK1oiUXyKcN0kv19sQeFn/J10uWJyvYvfg4rqNoL6J29VbmSX6RrVBZxFLQS2knjkjQOOrJ3oHfPapHaIfM1rUjzfTVXihVy/5sx/gtD7VuX0G@At291r@po3jA1X5UVrOOoKt1tey2n7GMqYzy6pGa3zuCn9PMXcHNv6yn3p2yxWR61xUtx3pbpvpH6QcTfuF179EHK/bmY5Y715/2zoiw25JaU9ecjXOvPx/S8oOfHftBGvm6Sr4l8TeTri3baoklbEG0xJkKv2fNVdJEPrvHP8f@YycEvJlV5oodP0uIPMXfotlf/YE36ZNHOp1cOdbrfkrj@YYLDlFA4Oz097vUKvCnAGwRH2f5Thw0yGg1x@2ydSEIUE2YYi2MbeF/quEJvn72Be4HLAZxCH@9L6PePevLYhtL1mm7Lhtrudn8A)

```java
/**
 * @param map a map of lists
 * @param <T> the type of the elements
 * @return the Cartesian product of map values
 */
public static <T> List<List<T>> cartesianProduct(Map<T, List<T>> map) {
    // check if incoming data is not null
    if (map == null) return Collections.emptyList();
    return map.values().stream().parallel()
            // non-null and non-empty lists
            .filter(list -> list != null && list.size() > 0)
            // represent each list element as a singleton list
            .map(list -> {
                List<List<T>> nList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
                for (T e : list) nList.add(Collections.singletonList(e));
                return nList;
            })
            // summation of pairs of inner lists
            .reduce((list1, list2) -> {
                // number of combinations
                int size = list1.size() * list2.size();
                // list of combinations
                List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<>(size);
                for (List<T> inner1 : list1)
                    for (List<T> inner2 : list2) {
                        List<T> inner = new ArrayList<>();
                        inner.addAll(inner1);
                        inner.addAll(inner2);
                        list.add(inner);
                    }
                return list;
            }).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("A", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"));
    map.put("B", Arrays.asList("B1", "B2", "B3"));
    map.put("C", Arrays.asList("C1", "C2"));

    List<List<String>> cp = cartesianProduct(map);
    // column-wise output
    int rows = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cp.size(); j++)
            System.out.print(j % rows == i ? cp.get(j) + " " : "");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[A1, B1, C1] [A2, B1, C1] [A3, B1, C1] [A4, B1, C1] 
[A1, B1, C2] [A2, B1, C2] [A3, B1, C2] [A4, B1, C2] 
[A1, B2, C1] [A2, B2, C1] [A3, B2, C1] [A4, B2, C1] 
[A1, B2, C2] [A2, B2, C2] [A3, B2, C2] [A4, B2, C2] 
[A1, B3, C1] [A2, B3, C1] [A3, B3, C1] [A4, B3, C1] 
[A1, B3, C2] [A2, B3, C2] [A3, B3, C2] [A4, B3, C2]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to get Cartesian product from multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68629936/16497917)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use a Consumer Function Class, a `List<T>` and a foreach

```java
public void tester() {
    String[] strs1 = {"2", "4", "9"};
    String[] strs2 = {"9", "0", "5"};

    //Final output is {"29", "49, 99", "20", "40", "90", "25", "45", "95"}
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Consumer<String> consumer = (String str) -> result.addAll(
            Arrays.stream(strs1).map(s -> s + str).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    Arrays.stream(strs2).forEach(consumer);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In loop create combined list

```java
List<String> cartesianProduct(List<List<String>> wordLists) {
    List<String> cp = wordLists.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < wordLists.size(); i++) {
        List<String> secondList = wordLists.get(i);
        List<String> combinedList = cp.stream()
                .flatMap(s1 -> secondList.stream()
                        .map(s2 -> s1 + s2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        cp = combinedList;
    }
    return cp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class implementing `Iterable`, and holding only the current item in memory. [The Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23932061) as well as [the Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511534) can be converted to a `Stream` if desired.

```java
class CartesianProduct<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {
  private final Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> factors;

  public CartesianProduct(final Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> factors) {
    this.factors = factors;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
    return new CartesianProductIterator<>(factors);
  }
}

class CartesianProductIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>> {
  private final List<Iterable<T>> factors;
  private final Stack<Iterator<T>> iterators;
  private final Stack<T> current;
  private List<T> next;
  private int index = 0;

  private void computeNext() {
    while (true) {
      if (iterators.get(index).hasNext()) {
        current.add(iterators.get(index).next());
        if (index == factors.size() - 1) {
          next = new ArrayList<>(current);
          current.pop();
          return;
        }
        index++;
        iterators.add(factors.get(index).iterator());
      } else {
        index--;
        if (index < 0) {
          return;
        }
        iterators.pop();
        current.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  public CartesianProductIterator(final Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> factors) {
    this.factors = StreamSupport.stream(factors.spliterator(), false)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    iterators = new Stack<>();
    current = new Stack<>();
    if (this.factors.size() == 0) {
      index = -1;
    } else {
      iterators.add(this.factors.get(0).iterator());
      computeNext();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    if (next == null && index >= 0) {
      computeNext();
    }
    return next != null;
  }

  @Override
  public List<T> next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    var result = next;
    next = null;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method as follows.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNb9NAEL3nV4wsIa1R6tJyoqWRoEICiQqkcEMc1s4kWXe9a3bHjQLqbw@za9cYnA8h4UNi78x7b752Svkgz8rF/W6nqto6gpIPsoaUzp5fT0ZnnhzKKpgmdZNrVUChpfdwJ5WBnxPgpzv3JIn/HqxaQMVWMSenzOrrN5Bu5dPOOTx3sn7dGqfwUXnqPmYzxtVwAwY3fG7ucfFe@nXwnon0uoezU1Y3JJI3SYvP7FIk8oK/EnkZf18m6T7A2yEgj4A8AvIDgNshoIiAIgKKFtAjYhp/5lJIR@iVNJ@dXTQFcWKB90HqBr1Iu8qKtOd4es7PwWHt0KMhQFmsQTMxoMYqnEgPEjxraCRrom1EkbGSiKizWfTo1aLl1mqNBSlr/NVVTxXCH0fTUxYt6Alsnc/IBoxI0wNJcNoItEZo1cEuYzAeyPY5tMnl230MHr83nLKSWm/BN1XFCKilcj5QdQWJ77SxLfW4FG0YIpbjYhq9LtOnulwcbsMgjsJWuTIyFiyoKWPQHdDrdZdaEs@uWHK4fR8uT@sNdCt0K4y5DRT5nctnDZ5kiL32WFizCPrz9irzKMeQptCaTkcySil0nQcn8v0D/OgEHW1AnBEu/LAR/3FSx7d3PEbWvdMeh1cnw6qmbcc72AVxYHRTmbON8gi2Id4lvZW7B85uPK@DV783zgdDXXucNCsUL6bRKd17s7/YT3kpVOjpHtzfeyfz6geKI/XNlkoTOlEGwhKedeHdgDqC6cOIqJHmCkmUKZe9LehR@T3tKq0yAZYAJPt6li25HbwZxXzrCXmmG57HmpVIm26PP04ed7tf)

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("A", List.of("a1", "a2", "a3"));
map.put("B", List.of("b1", "b2", "b3"));
map.put("C", List.of("c1", "c2", "c3"));
```

```java
List<List<String>> cartesianProduct = map.values().stream()
        // represent each list element as a singleton list
        .map(list -> list.stream().map(Collections::singletonList)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // reduce the stream of lists to a single list by
        // sequentially summing pairs of elements of two lists
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // combinations of inner lists
                .flatMap(first -> list2.stream()
                        // merge two inner lists into one
                        .map(second -> Stream.of(first, second)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                // list of combinations
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // List<List<String>>
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

```java
// column-wise output
int rows = 9;
IntStream.range(0, rows)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, cartesianProduct.size())
                .filter(j -> j % rows == i)
                .mapToObj(j -> cartesianProduct.get(j).toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("  ")))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[a1, b1, c1]  [a2, b1, c1]  [a3, b1, c1]
[a1, b1, c2]  [a2, b1, c2]  [a3, b1, c2]
[a1, b1, c3]  [a2, b1, c3]  [a3, b1, c3]
[a1, b2, c1]  [a2, b2, c1]  [a3, b2, c1]
[a1, b2, c2]  [a2, b2, c2]  [a3, b2, c2]
[a1, b2, c3]  [a2, b2, c3]  [a3, b2, c3]
[a1, b3, c1]  [a2, b3, c1]  [a3, b3, c1]
[a1, b3, c2]  [a2, b3, c2]  [a3, b3, c2]
[a1, b3, c3]  [a2, b3, c3]  [a3, b3, c3]
```

---

<sup>See also: [String permutations using recursion in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67114390/15613375)</sup>