# Cartesian product of streams in Java 8 as stream (using streams only)

Tags: java, set, java-8, java-stream, cartesian-product

I would like to create a method which creates a stream of elements which are cartesian products of multiple given streams (aggregated to the same type at the end by a binary operator). Please note that both arguments and results are streams, *not* collections.

For example, for two streams of **{A, B}** and **{X, Y}** I would like it produce stream of values **{AX, AY, BX, BY}** (simple concatenation is used for aggregating the strings). So far, I have came up with this code:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BinaryOperator<T> aggregator, Stream<T>... streams) {
    Stream<T> result = null;

    for (Stream<T> stream : streams) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = stream;
        } else {
            result = result.flatMap(m -> stream.map(n -> aggregator.apply(m, n)));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is my desired use case:

```
Stream<String> result = cartesian(
  (a, b) -> a + b, 
  Stream.of("A", "B"), 
  Stream.of("X", "Y")
);

System.out.println(result.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Expected result: `AX, AY, BX, BY`.

Another example:

```
Stream<String> result = cartesian(
  (a, b) -> a + b, 
  Stream.of("A", "B"), 
  Stream.of("K", "L"), 
  Stream.of("X", "Y")
);
```

Expected result: `AKX, AKY, ALX, ALY, BKX, BKY, BLX, BLY`.

However, if I run the code, I get this error:

**IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed**

Where is the stream consumed? By *flatMap*? Can it be easily fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Cartesian product with Java 8 streams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131987/how-can-i-make-cartesian-product-with-java-8-streams)

Comment: @mkobit: it is similar, but i think it is not a duplicate, as here you do not work with collections in arguments, but streams, which can lead to a different approach

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Passing the streams in your example is never better than passing Lists:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BinaryOperator<T> aggregator, List<T>... lists) {
    ...
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Stream<String> result = cartesian(
  (a, b) -> a + b, 
  Arrays.asList("A", "B"), 
  Arrays.asList("K", "L"), 
  Arrays.asList("X", "Y")
);
```

In both cases you create an implicit array from varargs and use it as data source, thus the laziness is imaginary. Your data is actually stored in the arrays.

In most of the cases the resulting Cartesian product stream is much longer than the inputs, thus there's practically no reason to make the inputs lazy. For example, having five lists of five elements (25 in total), you will have the resulting stream of 3125 elements. So storing 25 elements in the memory is not very big problem. Actually in most of the practical cases they are already stored in the memory.

In order to generate the stream of Cartesian products you need to constantly "rewind" all the streams (except the first one). To rewind, the streams should be able to retrieve the original data again and again, either buffering them somehow (which you don't like) or grabbing them again from the source (colleciton, array, file, network, random numbers, etc.) and perform again and again all the intermediate operations. If your source and intermediate operations are slow, then lazy solution may be much slower than buffering solution. If your source is unable to produce the data again (for example, random numbers generator which cannot produce the same numbers it produced before), your solution will be incorrect.

Nevertheless totally lazy solution is possbile. Just use not streams, but stream suppliers:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BinaryOperator<T> aggregator,
                                       Supplier<Stream<T>>... streams) {
    return Arrays.stream(streams)
        .reduce((s1, s2) -> 
            () -> s1.get().flatMap(t1 -> s2.get().map(t2 -> aggregator.apply(t1, t2))))
        .orElse(Stream::empty).get();
}
```

The solution is interesting as we create and reduce the stream of suppliers to get the resulting supplier and finally call it. Usage:

```
Stream<String> result = cartesian(
          (a, b) -> a + b, 
          () -> Stream.of("A", "B"), 
          () -> Stream.of("K", "L"), 
          () -> Stream.of("X", "Y")
        );
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: thank you for a great answer! i like both solutions and you are right. there are probably no reasonable examples where preferring stream in input would make much sense.

Comment: I'm just concerned about the efficiency here. It seems you are effectively creating a nexted stack of suppliers that is then called. Would it be better to create intermediate structures like Lists,  i.e. `List<T>... lists` instead of the `streams` array?

Answer (score 4):

`stream` is consumed in the `flatMap` operation in the second iteration. So you have to create a new stream every time you `map` your result. Therefore you have to collect the `stream` in advance to get a new stream in every iteration.

```
private static <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BiFunction<T, T, T> aggregator, Stream<T>... streams) {
    Stream<T> result = null;
    for (Stream<T> stream : streams) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = stream;
        } else {
            Collection<T> s = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
            result = result.flatMap(m -> s.stream().map(n -> aggregator.apply(m, n)));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BiFunction<T, T, T> aggregator, Stream<T>... streams) {
    return Arrays.stream(streams).reduce((r, s) -> {
        List<T> collect = s.collect(Collectors.toList());
        return r.flatMap(m -> collect.stream().map(n -> aggregator.apply(m, n)));
    }).orElse(Stream.empty());
}
```

Comment: thanks very much! do you think there is any way of doing this without buffering?

Comment: @voho I think this is not possible.

Comment: what i find strange is that this works: Collection<T> s = stream.collect(Collectors.toList()); result = result.flatMap(m -> s.stream().map(n -> aggregator.apply(m, n))); but this does not: Stream<T> s = stream.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream(); result = result.flatMap(m -> s.map(n -> aggregator.apply(m, n))); - although it is the same ?!

Comment: OK, I will mark your answer as correct, because it does what I wanted. Now I wonder if somebody comes with a solution that does not need collections...

Comment: It does not work with the collector in the statement because you connect the same stream to multiple 'collect' terminal oprations and this isn't allowed. This is the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method that returns a *stream of `List<T>`* of objects and does not aggregate them. The algorithm is the same: at each step, collect the elements of the second stream to a list and then append them to the elements of the first stream.

The aggregator is outside the method.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> cartesianProduct(Stream<T>... streams) {
    // incorrect incoming data
    if (streams == null) return Stream.empty();
    return Arrays.stream(streams)
            // non-null streams
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            // represent each list element as SingletonList<Object>
            .map(stream -> stream.map(Collections::singletonList))
            // summation of pairs of inner lists
            .reduce((stream1, stream2) -> {
                // list of lists from second stream
                List<List<T>> list2 = stream2.collect(Collectors.toList());
                // append to the first stream
                return stream1.flatMap(inner1 -> list2.stream()
                        // combinations of inner lists
                        .map(inner2 -> {
                            List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            list.addAll(inner1);
                            list.addAll(inner2);
                            return list;
                        }));
            }).orElse(Stream.empty());
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of("A", "B");
    Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of("K", "L");
    Stream<String> stream3 = Stream.of("X", "Y");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Stream<List<String>> stream4 = cartesianProduct(stream1, stream2, stream3);
    // output
    stream4.map(list -> String.join("", list)).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

`String.join` is a kind of aggregator in this case.

Output:

```
AKX
AKY
ALX
ALY
BKX
BKY
BLX
BLY
```

---

<sup>See also: [Stream of cartesian product of other streams, each element as a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67185626/15675591)</sup>