# Cartesian product using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a cartesian product function in JavaScript:

```
function cartesianProduct(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
        return a.map(function(x) {
            return b.map(function(y) {
                return x.concat(y);
            });
        }).reduce(function(a,b) { return a.concat(b); }, []);
    }, [[]]);
}
```

So that if I have a 3D array:

```
var data = [[['D']], [['E'],['L','M','N']]];
```

The result of `cartesianProduct(data)` would be the 2D array:

```
[['D','E'], ['D','L','M','N']]
```

**What I'm trying to do is write this cartesian product function in Java using Streams.**

So far I have the following in Java:

```
public Collection<Collection<String>> cartesianProduct(Collection<Collection<Collection<String>>> arr) {

    return arr.stream().reduce(new ArrayList<Collection<String>>(), (a, b) -> {
        return a.stream().map(x -> {
            return b.stream().map(y -> {
                return Stream.concat(x.stream(), y.stream());
            });
        }).reduce(new ArrayList<String>(), (c, d) -> {
            return Stream.concat(c, d);
        });
    });
}
```

I have a type checking error that states:

> `ArrayList<String>` is not compatible with `Stream<Stream<String>>`

My guesses as to what is wrong:

- I need to use a collector somewhere (maybe after the `Stream.concat`)
- The data type for the identity is wrong

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131987/how-can-i-make-cartesian-product-with-java-8-streams or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631602/cartesian-product-of-streams-in-java-8-as-stream-using-streams-only

Comment: What the hell does this have to do with the cross product?

Comment: I don't think a Stream is the right model here. A Stream takes elements of a single list/set/pool/whatever and does something with them. But you're trying to take elements from two separate entities and combining them in a specific way. You can use lambda expressions to represent all of your JavaScript closures, but I don't think a Stream is the right tool.

Comment: @michaelsnowden It's an attempt to implement a cross product function using Java streams. Do you have anything of actual value to add to the discussion or are you still confused?

Comment: @Bobulous The more I've learned about Streams this past week the more I'm coming to this realization. I think I'm treating Streams too much like closures in functional programming.

Comment: @michaelsnowden unless your pointing out my error in calling it a cross product rather than a Cartesian product?

Comment: @Craig It's not a Cartesian product either.

Comment: @Craig Oh, I see. You're doing an n-ary Cartesian product. It would help to clarify that in your question because "cross product" usually means "vector cross product" and the Cartesian product is usually between two sets, not n sets. Perhaps you should edit your question with this clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a bit of functional programming magic. Here's method which accepts `Collection<Collection<Collection<T>>>` and produces `Stream<Collection<T>>`:

```
static <T> Stream<Collection<T>> cartesianProduct(Collection<Collection<Collection<T>>> arr)
{
    return arr.stream()
        .<Supplier<Stream<Collection<T>>>> map(c -> c::stream)
        .reduce((s1, s2) -> () -> s1.get().flatMap(
                a -> s2.get().map(b -> Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))))
        .orElseGet(() -> () -> Stream.<Collection<T>>of(Collections.emptyList()))
        .get();
}
```

Usage example:

```
cartesianProduct(
    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("D")),
        Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("E"), Arrays.asList("L", "M", "N"))))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[D, E]
[D, L, M, N]
```

Of course instead of `.forEach()` you can collect the results to the `List` if you want to return `Collection<Collection<T>>` instead, but returning `Stream` seems more flexible to me.

A bit of explanation:

Here we create a stream of stream suppliers via `map(c -> c::stream)`. Each function of this stream may produce by demand a stream of the corresponding collection elements. We do this because streams a once off (otherwise having stream of streams would be enough). After that we reduce this stream of suppliers creating a new supplier for each pair which flatMaps two streams and maps their elements to the concatenated lists. The `orElseGet` part is necessary to handle the empty input. The last `.get()` just calls the final stream supplier to get the resulting stream.