# Stream of cartesian product of other streams, each element as a List?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, cartesian-product

How can I implement a function using Java 8 to take some number of streams, and produce a stream in which each element is a list consisting of one member of the Cartesian product of the streams?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631602/cartesian-product-of-streams-in-java-8-as-stream-using-streams-only) -- that question uses an aggregator that is a `BinaryOperator` (taking two items of like type and producing an item of the same type). I'd like the items in the end result to be `List`s rather than the types of the elements in the input streams.

Concretely, supposing my desired function is called `product`, the following:

```java
Stream<List<String>> result =
    product(
        Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D"),
        Stream.of("I", "J", "K"),
        Stream.of("Y", "Z")
    );

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

should print:

```
[A, I, Y]
[A, I, Z]
[A, J, Y]
[A, J, Z]
[A, K, Y]
[A, K, Z]
[B, I, Y]
...
[D, K, Y]
[D, K, Z]
```

Ideally, I'd like for this operation to be as lazy as possible. For example, if the input streams are produced by `Stream.generate()`, it'd be great if the suppliers of those streams weren't executed until absolutely needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows:

```java
private static <T> Stream<List<T>> product(Stream<T>... streams) {
    if (streams.length == 0) {
        return Stream.empty();
    }
    List<List<T>> cartesian = streams[streams.length - 1]
            .map(x -> Collections.singletonList(x))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = streams.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        final List<List<T>> previous = cartesian;
        cartesian = streams[i].flatMap(x -> previous.stream().map(p -> {
            final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(p.size() + 1);
            list.add(x);
            list.addAll(p);
            return list;
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return cartesian.stream();
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    final Stream<List<String>> result =
            product(
                    Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    Stream.of("I", "J", "K"),
                    Stream.of("Y", "Z")
            );

    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The product-call returns a `Stream<List<String>>` result which prints as

```
[A, I, Y]
[A, I, Z]
[A, J, Y]
[A, J, Z]
[A, K, Y]
[A, K, Z]
[B, I, Y]
[B, I, Z]
[B, J, Y]
[B, J, Z]
[B, K, Y]
[B, K, Z]
[C, I, Y]
[C, I, Z]
[C, J, Y]
[C, J, Z]
[C, K, Y]
[C, K, Z]
[D, I, Y]
[D, I, Z]
[D, J, Y]
[D, J, Z]
[D, K, Y]
[D, K, Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like this:

```java
List<Stream<String>> listStreams = List.of(
        Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D"),
        Stream.of("I", "J", "K"),
        Stream.of("Y", "Z"));

Stream<List<String>> streamLists = listStreams.stream()
        // represent each list element as SingletonList<Object>
        .map(stream -> stream.map(Collections::singletonList))
        // summation of pairs of inner lists
        .reduce((stream1, stream2) -> {
            // list of lists from second stream
            List<List<String>> list2 = stream2.collect(Collectors.toList());
            // append to the first stream
            return stream1.flatMap(inner1 -> list2.stream()
                    // combinations of inner lists
                    .map(inner2 -> {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.addAll(inner1);
                        list.addAll(inner2);
                        return list;
                    }));
        }).orElse(Stream.empty());

// output
streamLists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[A, I, Y]
[A, I, Z]
[A, J, Y]
[A, J, Z]
[A, K, Y]
[A, K, Z]
[B, I, Y]
[B, I, Z]
[B, J, Y]
[B, J, Z]
[B, K, Y]
[B, K, Z]
[C, I, Y]
[C, I, Z]
[C, J, Y]
[C, J, Z]
[C, K, Y]
[C, K, Z]
[D, I, Y]
[D, I, Z]
[D, J, Y]
[D, J, Z]
[D, K, Y]
[D, K, Z]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Find cartesian product of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67156330/15675591)</sup>