# Convert classic nested for loop with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream, nested-loops

I want to convert the following code using the Java 8 stream API

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
for (Suit s: Suit.values())
{
    for (Rank r: Rank.values())
    {
        deck .add(new Card(r, s));
    }
}
```

I came out with this

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.stream(Suit.values())
    .forEach(s -> Arrays.stream(Rank.values())
        .forEach(r -> deck.add(new Card(r, s))));
```

but I don't like it as it has a side-effect on the list.

Is there another elegant way, producing a list from a stream instead maybe?

Comment: What do you mean "*it has a side-effect on the list*"? What is the side-effect?

Comment: As the above comment points out, what does 'side-effects' mean? Also you can try to see if you can stream both lists and then collect your outcome in a new list. 

Bear in mind though, that it's not always efficient to use streams as they tend to have big processing overhead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
List<Card> cards = Arrays.stream(Suit.values())
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(Rank.values()).map(r -> new Card(r, s)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Actually it is simple Cartesian product. I took an example from [Cartesian product of streams in Java 8 as stream (using streams only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631602/cartesian-product-of-streams-in-java-8-as-stream-using-streams-only) and adapted to your case. If you want to make third loop inside you need to use code from this answer.

Comment: Why not instead vote to close the question as a duplicate. The answers found in the duplicate are far more comprehensive and detailed.