# Simplifing the Nested for-loop using Stream API

Tags: java, set, java-stream

I am trying to achieve the following by converting two for loops using Java Streams.

```
Set<Type2> set = new HashSet<>();

for (Test1 test1 : testlist1) {           // testlist1 is a list
    for (Test2 test2 : test1.getList()) { // test1.getList() returns a list
        set.add(test2);
    }
}
```

New to Java streams and trying to convert it.

Comment: Nested `for`-loops could be used perfectly well for generating [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), as described in [this currently associated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653798/convert-classic-nested-for-loop-with-java-8-streams). But the question listed above has nothing to do with Cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) to achieve the same result:

```
Set<Type2> set = testlist1.stream()             // Stream<Type1>
    .flatMap(test1 -> test1.getList().stream()) // Stream<Type2>
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Another option is to use Java 16 [`Stream.mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)), which would be more performant than `flatMap()` in case if lists returned by `test1.getList()` would contain only a few elements or even can be empty.

```
Set<Type2> set = testlist1.stream()
    .<Type2>mapMulti((test1, c) -> test1.getList().forEach(c))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```